# Text to Captcha Image using java

Tags: java, captcha

How to convert text to captcha image.

EDIT

i looked at jcaptcha. It creates a random text for a id. But i need
a image with the given text.

Comment: For Jcaptcha have a look at the WordGenerator create your own if you wish. You could supply your own words to it. There is a ConstantWordGenerator too.

Answer (score 1):

Jcaptcha provides classes to convert a text into image.

sample code:

```
WordToImage image =  ComposedWordToImage(fontGenerator, background,textPaster);
BufferedImage image = image.getImage("text");
```

api doc of [WordToImage](http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/apidocs/2.0-alpha1/com/octo/captcha/component/image/wordtoimage/WordToImage.html) interface